# LinkedList palindrome recursion solution

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I'm reading a coding book and am having difficulty understanding the solution for checking whether a LinkedList is a palindrome.

The solution provided is as follows:

```
public class Result {
    public LinkedListNode node;
    public boolean result;
}

public Result isPalindromeRecurse(LinkedListNode head, int length) {
    if (head == null || length == 0) {
        return new Result(null, true);
    } else if (length == 1) {
        return new Result(head.next, true);
    } else if (length == 2) {
        return new Result(head.next.next, head.data == head.next.data);
    }
    Result res = isPalindromeRecurse(head.next, length - 2);
    if (!res.result || res.node == null) {
        return res; 
    } else {
        res.result = head.data == res.node.data;
        res.node = res.node.next;
        return res;
    }
}

public boolean isPalindrome(LinkedListNode head) {
    Result p = isPalindromeRecurse(head, size);
    return p.result;
}
```

I understand the overall logic, in that passing length-2 allows us to know once we have reached the middle element to help form the base case.  However, I am having trouble visualizing how, other than the base case comparisons, the other node comparisons are made that are nearer to the middle element.  If anyone can explain this to me and help step me through the code and recursion, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a list containing

```
A B C D E F
```

The algorithm consists in the following recursive rule: `A B C D E F` is a palindrome if `B C D E` is a palindrome and `A` is equal to the element following `E`.

If you apply the rule recursively, you also have: `B C D E` is a palindrome if `C D` is a palindrome and `B` is equal to the element following `D`.

And then you're at the base case where length is 2, where the rule is that `C D`is a palindrome if `C` is equal to `D`.

That's why the result class contains a boolean (true or false), and a node. This node is the last node of the examined sequence, which allows the next step to get the element following the last node of the previous step.

Comment: Thanks!  I understand that logic, but am still struggling to see it reflected in the code.  For example, if our list is as follows:  1->2->3->4->5.  We have the recursion in the following order: isPalindromeRecurse(head.next, 5), res = isPalindromeRecurse(head.next, 3), res = isPalindromeRecurse(head.next, 1).  The latter one runs first, and it's already the base case?  So what happens, does res = Result(head.next, true)?  Then, what?  I'm just having trouble stepping through this code, if someone can help me step through it to understand it.

Comment: You should use a debugger and step through the code, inspecting the variables as you go.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the code is going to recurse until it reaches the middle of the list. Then, you need to compare all pairs of index `(i, length - i - 1)`, starting from the middle. The element of index `i` is pointed by `head`, the element of the second index is pointed by `res.node`.

What happens is that the recursive call is going to push the `head` pointer to the middle, and when it will return, `res.node` will be the symmetric element of `head`. Then, you return a new result containing `node.next`, and you are going to handle this result in the previous recursive called, where the `head` was the predecessor of the current head. Therefore, you are pushing `res.node` to the right and `head` to the left : they are still symmetric elements.